# In "C++: Concurrency in Action", why use reference counting/hazard variables instead of std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>?

Tags: c++, concurrency, lock-free, stdatomic

I'm learning about lock-free data structures from *C++: Concurrency in Action*, a textbook by Anthony Williams. The running example is a lock-free stack.

Williams uses the following pseudocode for `pop` (p. 186):

> 1 Read the current value of head.
> 2 Read head->next.
> 3 Set head to head->next.
> 4 Return the data from the retrieved node.
> 5 Delete the retrieved node.

The code for this WITHOUT step 5 is:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
    node* old_head=head.load();
    while(old_head &&
        !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head,old_head->next));
    return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
}
```

He says, "If one thread then proceeds all the way through to step 5 before the other gets to step 2, the second thread will be dereferencing a dangling pointer." This makes sense to me. He then goes on to propose several solutions for the issue, such as reference counting/garbage collection.

My question is: **Why can't we just wrap the nodes in atomic smart pointers?** Wouldn't they do all the resource cleanup for us?

Comment: Mostly because `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is [not actually lock free](https://godbolt.org/z/WjjqY8hKd) in the standard library implementations so far. There was even a [talk at CppCon about the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OS7Asaa6zmY), and it's a non-trivial problem to solve.

Comment: @chris_se The standard says, "All atomic types except for std::atomic_flag may be implemented using mutexes or other locking operations". So, I think that Williams is using the phrase "lock-free data structure" to mean "a data structure that can be accessed safely by multiple threads without using programmer-defined mutexes". Maybe the talk will clear things up though--thanks for the link!

Comment: While that's true regarding the standard, in practice on all reasonable CPUs all atomic integer data types up to the size of a pointer and all atomic bare pointers are lock-free. Lock-free and wait-free in concurrency have actual definitions regarding the forward progress the program / individual threads make, and I'm very sure that Williams means those specifically. That a theoretical compiler could have `atomic<int>` not be lock-free might be true in principle, but in practice that's simply not relevant.

Comment: @chris_se That makes sense, then. Appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an atomic smart pointer if you want to implement a lock-free stack. The atomic smart pointer uses locks.

Answer (score 0):

Not read the book but definitely this code has the problem of dangling pointer and ABA problem. You are right about the usage of atomic<shared_ptr>, which should take care of [ABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) and resource management. You can refer this paper from Herb Sutter for detailed explanation.
[https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4058.pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)